# Realm Android Multi User Login

Tags: java, android, kotlin, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I am using Realm in my Android project and the app requirements is to allow data of multiple users to co-exist. I am not able to implement the same as I didn’t get any tutorial on web.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you saying you were unable to locate the [Getting Started Guide](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/tutorial/java-sdk/) which includes a section about [User Authentication](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/tutorial/java-sdk/#enable-authentication)?

Comment: @Jay Thanks for your answer but in the above implementation realm is syncing with server , but in my app we are not doing the same.

Comment: Perhaps you over looked the link **If your application only requires local Realm Database functionality, you should follow the** [Quick Start - Java SDK](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/java/quick-start-local/#std-label-java-client-quick-start-local) which says *This Guide Does Not Use Realm Sync*